# Device tree - generic-uio is not instantiated

Tags: android, generics, device-tree

I have a problem with device tree, in particular with "`generic-uio`".
I have this device tree (it refers to `Zynq 7020`):

```
/ {
compatible = "xlnx,zynq-7000";
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <1>;
interrupt-parent = <&gic>;

aliases {
    ethernet0 = &eth;
    serial0 = &uart1;
};

cpus {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    ps7_cortexa9_0: cpu@0 {
        bus-handle = <&axi>;
        clock-latency = <1000>;
        clocks = <&clkc 3>;
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
        device_type = "cpu";
        interrupt-handle = <&gic>;
        operating-points = <666667 1000000 333334 1000000 222223 1000000>;
        reg = <0x0>;
    };

    ps7_cortexa9_1: cpu@1 {
        bus-handle = <&axi>;
        clocks = <&clkc 3>;
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
        device_type = "cpu";
        interrupt-handle = <&gic>;
        reg = <0x1>;
    };
};

pmu {
    compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-pmu";
    interrupts = <0 5 4>, <0 6 4>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    reg = <0xf8891000 0x1000>, <0xf8893000 0x1000>;
    reg-names = "cpu0", "cpu1";
};

axi: amba@0 {
    compatible = "simple-bus";
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x1>;
    ranges;

    gic: intc@f8f01000 {
        interrupt-controller;
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
        #interrupt-cells = <3>;
        reg = <0xf8f01000 0x1000>,
              <0xf8f00100 0x0100>;
    };

    pl310@f8f02000 {
        compatible = "arm,pl310-cache";
        cache-unified;
        cache-level = <2>;
        reg = <0xf8f02000 0x1000>;
        arm,data-latency = <3 2 2>;
        arm,tag-latency = <2 2 2>;
    };

    uart0: uart@e0000000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,xuartps";
        status = "disabled";
        reg = <0xe0000000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0 27 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
        clocks = <&clkc 23>, <&clkc 40>;
        port-number = <0>;
        current-speed = <115200>;
        device_type = "serial";
    };

    uart1: uart@e0001000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,xuartps";
        reg = <0xe0001000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = < 0 50 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
        clocks = <&clkc 24>, <&clkc 41>;
        port-number = <0>;
        current-speed = <115200>;
        device_type = "serial";
    };

    ps7_dma: ps7-dma@f8003000 {
        #dma-cells = <1>;
        #dma-channels = <8>;
        #dma-requests = <4>;
        compatible = "arm,primecell", "arm,pl330";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 13 4 0 14 4 0 15 4 0 16 4 0 17 4 0 40 4 0 41 4 0 42 4 0 43 4>;
        reg = <0xf8003000 0x1000>;
        clocks = <&clkc 27>;
        clock-names = "apb_pclk";
    };

    /******* SEE HERE - SLCR *******/
    slcr: slcr@f8000000 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        //generic-uio has been added 
        compatible = "generic-uio", "xlnx,zynq-slcr","syscon";
        reg = <0xf8000000 0x1000>;
        ranges;
        clkc: clkc {
            #clock-cells = <1>;
            clock-output-names = "armpll", "ddrpll", "iopll", "cpu_6or4x", "cpu_3or2x",
                "cpu_2x", "cpu_1x", "ddr2x", "ddr3x", "dci",
                "lqspi", "smc", "pcap", "gem0", "gem1",
                "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3", "can0",
                "can1", "sdio0", "sdio1", "uart0", "uart1",
                "spi0", "spi1", "dma", "usb0_aper", "usb1_aper",
                "gem0_aper", "gem1_aper", "sdio0_aper", "sdio1_aper", "spi0_aper",
                "spi1_aper", "can0_aper", "can1_aper", "i2c0_aper", "i2c1_aper",
                "uart0_aper", "uart1_aper", "gpio_aper", "lqspi_aper", "smc_aper",
                "swdt", "dbg_trc", "dbg_apb";
            compatible = "xlnx,ps7-clkc";
            ps-clk-frequency = <33333333>;
            fclk-enable = <0xf>;
            reg = <0x100 0x100>;
        };
    };

    timer@0xf8001000 {
        compatible = "cdns,ttc";
        reg = <0xf8001000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = < 0 10 4 0 11 4 0 12 4 >;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 6>;
    };

    timer@f8f00600 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-twd-timer";
        reg = <0xf8f00600 0x20>;
        interrupts = <1 13 0x301>;
        clocks = <&clkc 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    };

    swdt@f8005000 {
        device_type = "watchdog";
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-wdt-1.00.a", "xlnx,zynq-wdt-1.00.a";
        reg = <0xf8005000 0x100>;
        interrupts = <0 9 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 45>;
        reset = <0>;
        timeout = <10>;
    };

    scuwdt@f8f00620 {
        device_type = "watchdog";
        compatible = "arm,mpcore_wdt";
        reg = <0xf8f00620 0x20>;
        clocks = <&clkc 4>;
        reset = <1>;
    };

    eth: eth@e000b000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-ethernet-1.00.a";
        reg = <0xe000b000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0 22 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;

        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
        clocks = <&clkc 13>, <&clkc 30>;

        xlnx,enet-clk-freq-hz = <0x17d7840>;
        xlnx,enet-reset = "MIO 11";
        xlnx,enet-slcr-1000mbps-div0 = <0x8>;
        xlnx,enet-slcr-1000mbps-div1 = <0x1>;
        xlnx,enet-slcr-100mbps-div0 = <0x8>;
        xlnx,enet-slcr-100mbps-div1 = <0x5>;
        xlnx,enet-slcr-10mbps-div0 = <0x8>;
        xlnx,enet-slcr-10mbps-div1 = <0x32>;
        xlnx,eth-mode = <0x1>;
        xlnx,has-mdio = <0x1>;
        xlnx,ptp-enet-clock = <111111115>;
    };

    gpio: gpio@e000a000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-gpio-1.00.a", "xlnx,zynq-gpio-1.00.a", "xlnx,zynq-gpio-1.0";
        reg = <0xe000a000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0 20 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 42>;
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <2>;
    };

    sdhci@e0100000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-sdio-1.00.a", "arasan,sdhci-8.9a";
        reg = <0xe0100000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0 24 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
        clocks = <&clkc 21>, <&clkc 32>;
        xlnx,has-cd = <0x1>;
        clock-frequency = <50000000>;
    };

    usb: usb@e0002000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-usb-1.00.a", "xlnx,zynq-usb-1.00.a";
        reg = <0xe0002000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0 21 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 28>;
        dr_mode = "host";
        phy_type = "ulpi";
    };

    spi0: spi@e0006000 {
        compatible = "cdns,spi-r1p6", "xlnx,zynq-spi-1.00.a", "xlnx,ps7-spi-1.00.a";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 26 4>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk", "pclk";
        clocks = <&clkc 25>, <&clkc 34>, <&clkc 34>;
        num-chip-select = <4>;
        reg = <0xe0006000 0x1000>;
        speed-hz = <100000000>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        status = "disabled";
    };

    spi1: spi@e0007000 {
        compatible = "cdns,spi-r1p6", "xlnx,zynq-spi-1.00.a", "xlnx,ps7-spi-1.00.a";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 49 4>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk", "pclk";
        clocks = <&clkc 26>, <&clkc 35>, <&clkc 35>;
        num-chip-select = <4>;
        reg = <0xe0007000 0x1000>;
        speed-hz = <100000000>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        status = "disabled";
    };

    qspi0: qspi@e000d000 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        bus-num = <0>;
        compatible = "xlnx,zynq-qspi-1.00.a", "xlnx,ps7-qspi-1.00.a";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 19 4>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "aper_clk";
        clocks = <&clkc 10>, <&clkc 43>;
        is-dual = <0>;
        num-chip-select = <1>;
        reg = <0xe000d000 0x1000>;
        xlnx,fb-clk = <0x1>;
        xlnx,qspi-clk-freq-hz = <0xbebc200>;
        xlnx,qspi-mode = <0x0>;
        primary_flash: ps7-qspi@0 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "st,m25p80";
            reg = <0x0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
            partition@0x00000000 {
                label = "boot";
                reg = <0x00000000 0x00500000>;
            };
            partition@0x00500000 {
                label = "bootenv";
                reg = <0x00500000 0x00020000>;
            };
            partition@0x00520000 {
                label = "config";
                reg = <0x00520000 0x00020000>;
            };
            partition@0x00540000 {
                label = "image";
                reg = <0x00540000 0x00a80000>;
            };
            partition@0x00fc0000 {
                label = "spare";
                reg = <0x00fc0000 0x00000000>;
            };
        };
    };

    devcfg@f8007000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,zynq-devcfg-1.0";
        reg = <0xf8007000 0x100>;
        interrupts = <0 8 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 12>, <&clkc 15>, <&clkc 16>, <&clkc 17>, <&clkc 18>;
        clock-names = "ref_clk", "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3";
    };

    xadc@f8007100 {
        compatible = "xlnx,zynq-xadc-1.00.a", "xlnx,ps7-xadc-1.00.a";
        reg = <0xf8007100 0x20>;
        interrupts = <0 7 4>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        clocks = <&clkc 12>;
    };

    ps7_ddrc_0: ps7-ddrc@f8006000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-ddrc-1.00.a", "xlnx,ps7-ddrc", "xlnx,zynq-ddrc-1.0";
        reg = <0xf8006000 0x1000>;
        xlnx,has-ecc = <0x0>;
    } ;

    ps7_ocm_0: ps7-ocm@f800c000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,ps7-ocmc-1.00.a", "xlnx,zynq-ocmc-1.0";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 3 4>;
        reg = <0xf800c000 0x1000>;
    };
};
};
```

I need to access the SLCR Register under a C user-space driver (which runs under Android), and because Android doesn't allow to open /dev/mem for security purpose, I  "`mmap`" the register through generic-uio (so I will open `/dev/uioX` an then call mmap).
However the kernel doesn't "assign" SLCR as generic-uio because I don't see it under `/dev/uio or /sys/class/uio/` (I only see UIOx assigned to other peripherals which are mapped successfully).

I think that is a problem related to the empty "`ranges`" property, but if I write something like "`ranges = <0 0 0xf8000000 0x1000>;`" I don't see any change.

**Could someone give me an hint?**

P.s. *I'm using a C user-space driver because I want reuse most of the code  written for a Linux app.*

Comment: Do you have UIO enable in the kernel? If so, have you got something like this in you bootargs:  uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio  ?